# How to Record Both Mic Audio and Speakers while using headset

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, recording

I'm trying to record my screen with sound at the same time, but right now, my jack stopped working (it's with the red light) and I have to use a headset so that I can have sound on my Mac.

So my question is: Can I record my screen, my audio input (me babbling) and the supposed audio output that should come from speakers (that now its coming out from my headset).

Is there a way, Or is it just impossible?

Comment: It was a huge hassle for me to figure this out. Here is a free way on Mac to record audio from your mic and what is playing through your speakers simultaneously (but not your screen): https://superuser.com/a/1426622/74576 When I want the screen too, I replace QuickTime with OBS, which is also free.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen many questions like this. The simple solution is Soundflower. You can download it for free at http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/. As to where you're recording, you would need to select the Soundflower (2ch) or Soundflower (16ch) as your input.

Input 1 = your microphone's audio/your babbling
Input 2 = your speakers' output

Comment: App not available anymore. And updates for 2021?

Answer (score 0):

This is very much possible using ScreenFlow: https://www.telestream.net/screenflow/overview.htm

It's a paid app but very high quality and straight forward to use. Whenever you create a new recording it gives you options of recording audio/video from all available inputs, including the screen, camera, microphone, and internal computer audio.